# draw circles of different radius in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, draw

i am trying to draw circles of different shapes but whatever the radius i enter it is creating a circle with fixed size radius(50mt)...can anybody help me here's my code

```
       //_accuracy=0.0; double radius=0.0;
        double metersPerPixels = (Math.Cos(geo.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137) / (256 * Math.Pow(2, MyMap.ZoomLevel));
        radius = _accuracy / metersPerPixels;
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Width = radius * 2;
        ellipse.Height = radius * 2;
        ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(75, 200, 0, 0));

        MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
        overlay.Content = ellipse;
        overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(geo.Latitude, geo.Longitude);
        overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        mapLayer.Add(overlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to create a fixed size circle. For it to be dynamic you need to use a ZoomLevelChanged callback:

```
//where myMap is defined
myMap.ZoomLevelChanged += myMapZoomLevelChanged;

//somewhere else in the code
private void myMapZoomLevelChanged(MapControl sender, object args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < circlesOnMap.Count; i++)
    {
        double metersPerPixel = (Math.Cos(geo.Position.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137) / (256 * Math.Pow(2, myMap.ZoomLevel));
        ellipse.Height = radiusInMeters / metersPerPixel * 2;
        ellipse.Width = radiusInMeters / metersPerPixel * 2;
    }
}
```